# Unwrapping string object in Swift 5.0 to [(Double, Double)]

Tags: swift

Trying to cast string to [(Double, Double)] in swift 5.0

```swift
let test: String = "[(0.0,1.0),(0.0,2.0)]"
let out: [(Double, Double)] = test as! [(Double, Double)]
```

Comment: Why do you have a string like that?

Comment: data from an rest api written in python. Is there an easier way that I could format it?

Comment: A JSON format would make parsing the data much simpler.

Comment: Is it supposed to be a 2x2 matrix or???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution (it is 3:30 am :-) )

```
let test: String = "[(0.0,1.0),(0.0,2.0)]"

let filtered = test.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "[](),")).filter{$0 != ""}
var output = [(Double, Double)]()
var i = 0
while i < filtered.count - 1 {
   if let a = Double(filtered[i]), let b = Double(filtered[i+1]){
      output.append((a,b))
   }
   i += 2
}
```

Comment: One liner: `let result = { doubles in (0..<doubles.count/2).map { (doubles[2 * $0], doubles[2 * $0 + 1]) }}(test.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "[](), ")).compactMap(Double.init))`